# In App Purchase with restore transaction

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Can anyone please explain me how restore transaction works with Auto-Renewable Subscriptions.

I have read apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5
But did not get this.

I have an application which does not have Login authentication. If user purchase the Product from one device and same user install the app on another device how can i know that the user who installed the app has already purchase the product.

if user goes to purchase the product they already purchase is there any delegate methods for it that we can know that is user has already purchase the product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to worry about the transaction. For such user, when he tries to purchase the item, store will inform him that he has already purchased the particular item. So he can download it for free.

Comment: Yes that's true but how can i know that this user has already purchase so i can give access to certain things. is there any delegate method from where i can know that user has already purchase the item?

Comment: As I worked on this, we can not know this until the user does the purchase again.

Comment: Ok, If i give button for Restore Purchase then how can i know that user has made Purchase or not? is there any delegate methods?

Comment: For your case, in other device you won't be knowing that user has already made the payment, so you can not name the button as restore. Unless the user tries for the purchase how can we get the delegate for that. I think there are no any such delegates.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, i just worked out with restore transaction button and it gives me last transaction receipt so i can check with that.